# How can I get cumulative sum using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of individual sales, for which I would like to summarize into two columns, with a monthly total in one and a cumulative sum in another.

Company A and Company B are subsidiary company under the same parent company, thus, need to be considered as one for calculating cumulative income.

I tried this code and output is following:

```
SUM(INCOME) OVER(PARTITION BY COMPANY ORDER BY MONTH ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CUMULATIVE
```

```
Company     Month     Income       Cumulative
Company A     1        20             20
Company B     1        0              20
Company C     1        20             20
Company A     2        20             40
Company B     2        0              40
```

But I want to return 0 when Company B has 0 income for cumulative

```
Company     Month     Income       Cumulative
Company A     1        20             20
Company B     1        0              0
Company C     1        20             20
Company A     2        20             40
Company B     2        0              0
```

How can I return 0 for cumulative when either company A or company B has income of 0?!

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL

Comment: the design is bad as you have no years and month names are bad to sort, which you will need to use the window function sum

Comment: Which version? There are a *lot* of versions since 1997. The window functions and the `OVER()` clause introduced in SQL Server 2014 make rolling aggregates a lot easier, eg `SUM(Income) OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Month)`

Comment: As for `need to be considered as one` there must be some kind of ID or field that combines these. If there is, you can group or partition by that field.

Comment: Don't ignore @nbk's comment - the correct code offered by Panagiotis will work, but it relies on the ability to ORDER.  you know that Jan comes before Feb but the database will order alphabetically, so you'd probably get a confusing result unless you had an actual date column to sort on for the month.

Comment: Hopefully your *month* column is just contrived for your example an you *actually* have a proper *date* data type column - in which case please show that, along with the sample data your desired results are based on.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad design for the prupose you want and need

adding an identidy field for sorting purposes and converting your short name into numbers, you can achieve it with window function.

A column for the year is also necessary as you can't sort when you got two janissary for the same company

```
CREATE TABLE tabl1 (
  id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),  
  Company VARCHAR(9),
  Month VARCHAR(3),
  Income INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tabl1
  (Company, Month, Income)
VALUES
  ('Company A', 'Jan', '20'),
  ('Company B', 'Jan', '0'),
  ('Company A', 'Feb', '20'),
  ('Company B', 'Feb', '0'),
  ('Company C', 'Jan', '20');
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
  Company, Month, Income, 
SUM(Income) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY
CASE WHEN Month= 'Jan' THEN 1
     WHEN Month = 'Feb' THEN 2
     WHEN Month = 'Dec' THEN 12

END) as Cumulative
FROM 
   tabl1
ORDER BY id_num
```

| Company | Month | Income | Cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | Jan | 20 | 20 |
| Company B | Jan | 0 | 0 |
| Company A | Feb | 20 | 40 |
| Company B | Feb | 0 | 0 |
| Company C | Jan | 20 | 20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nry_yke5)

So a better would be

```
CREATE TABLE tabl1 (
  id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),  
  Company VARCHAR(9),
  Month VARCHAR(3),
  [Year] int,
  Income INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tabl1
  (Company, Month,[Year], Income)
VALUES
  ('Company A', 'Jan',2023, '20'),
  ('Company B', 'Jan',2023, '0'),
  ('Company A', 'Feb',2023, '20'),
  ('Company B', 'Feb',2023, '0'),
  ('Company C', 'Jan',2023, '20');
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
  Company, Month,[Year], Income, 
SUM(Income) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY
CASE WHEN Month= 'Jan' THEN 1
     WHEN Month = 'Feb' THEN 2
     WHEN Month = 'Dec' THEN 12

END, YEAR ) as Cumulative
FROM 
   tabl1
ORDER BY id_num
```

| Company | Month | Year | Income | Cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | Jan | 2023 | 20 | 20 |
| Company B | Jan | 2023 | 0 | 0 |
| Company A | Feb | 2023 | 20 | 40 |
| Company B | Feb | 2023 | 0 | 0 |
| Company C | Jan | 2023 | 20 | 20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k3hek6hP)